# Hibernate - Connection is read-only when I stress the system

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have an application using Spring 4.3 with Hibernate 5.1.17 and MySQL 5.7.27 database. For some reason, when I stress the system with JMeter app, this kind of methods generate *Connection is read-only exception*:

```
Service1.method() {
       call to Service2.methodreadonly() with transactional(read-only=true)
       call to Service3.methodnoreadonly() with transactional()
}
```

When JMeter calls multiple times to Service1.method() sometimes hibernate / mysql produces next exception:

```
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
```

I tried the same with SQL Server engine and works fine.

This error is usually generated when JMeter launches 10 threads, with less threads or without concurrency the error doesnt occurs.

JPA important configuration is:

```
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.handling_mode" value="DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
```

I don't understand why hibernate sometimes is reusing the session or why mysql returns the same session in differents @Transactional annotations

Comment: Maybe you have something about `thread safeness` or something related to the fact that `Service1` should be transactional AND spread it's own transaction to the `Service2` and `Service3`.

Comment: After hours of debugging / testing, I have found the solution:

Configuring in *org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource* the variable defaultReadOnly set to false.

I don't know why, but this flag solve the problem

Comment: Seems logic, you error was about a refused data modification, probably becuause default request are set to `read-only = true`.

Comment: but the exception only occurs when there are multiple requests and maybe one time of 20 o 30 simultaneous requests.

Comment: 乁( •_• )ㄏ You should search more.